# core.js:5873 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined

Tags: node.js, angular, httpclient, undefined, express-router

I am trying to store some images on my Node.JS server and read it from Angular client with the following codes:

image.ts:

```
export class Image {
    fieldname: string;
    originalname: string;
    encoding: string;
    mimetype: string;
    destination: string;
    filename: string;
    path: string;
    size: number;
}
```

image.service.ts:

```
export class ImagesService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
    private processHTTPMsgService: ProcessHTTPMsgService) { }

  getImages(): Observable<Image[]> {
    return this.http.get<Image[]>(baseURL + 'images')
      .pipe(catchError(this.processHTTPMsgService.handleError));
  }

}
```

models/image.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var imageSchema = new Schema({
  fieldname: {
      type: String
  },
  originalname: {
      type: String
  },
  encoding: {
      type: String
  },
  mimetype: {
      type: String
  },
  destination: {
      type: String
  },
  filename: {
      type: String
  },
  path: {
      type: String
  },
  size:{
    type: Number
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true
});

var Images = mongoose.model('Image', imageSchema);
module.exports = Images ;
```

imagesRouter.js:

```
imagesRouter.route('/')
.get(cors.cors, (req,res,next) => {
    Images.find({})
    .then((images) => {
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.json(images);

    }, (err) => next(err))
    .catch((err) => next(err));
})



module.exports = imagesRouter;
```

And the uploadRouter.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const authenticate = require('../authenticate');
const multer = require('multer');
const cors = require('./cors');
const Images = require('../models/images');


const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'public/images');
    },

    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
});

const imageFileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if(!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/)) {
        return cb(new Error('You can upload only image files!'), false);
    }
    cb(null, true);
};

const upload = multer({ storage: storage, fileFilter: imageFileFilter});

const uploadRouter = express.Router();
uploadRouter.use(bodyParser.json());

uploadRouter.route('/')

.post(cors.corsWithOptions, authenticate.verifyUser, authenticate.verifyAdmin, upload.single('imageFile'),
 (req, res, next) => {
    Images.create(req.file)
    .then((image) => {
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.json(req.file);
    }, (err) => next(err))
    .catch((err) => next(err));


})
```

I can upload images successfully using Postman, and I get the result like following:

```
{
    "fieldname": "imageFile",
    "originalname": "home_header.jpg",
    "encoding": "7bit",
    "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
    "destination": "public/images",
    "filename": "home_header.jpg",
    "path": "public\\images\\home_header.jpg",
    "size": 58277
}
```

And it will be stored in MongoDB like this:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e9051503af5a25cc487abe8"),
        "fieldname" : "imageFile",
        "originalname" : "home_header.jpg",
        "encoding" : "7bit",
        "mimetype" : "image/jpeg",
        "destination" : "public/images",
        "filename" : "home_header.jpg",
        "path" : "public\\images\\home_header.jpg",
        "size" : 58277,
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-04-10T10:58:24.710Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-04-10T10:58:24.710Z"),
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e90519c40aea44ca84df4ca"),
        "fieldname" : "imageFile",
        "originalname" : "logo.png",
        "encoding" : "7bit",
        "mimetype" : "image/png",
        "destination" : "public/images",
        "filename" : "logo.png",
        "path" : "public\\images\\logo.png",
        "size" : 18534,
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-04-10T10:59:40.979Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-04-10T10:59:40.979Z"),
        "__v" : 0
}
```

But I don't know what is the problem that I can's see the images on my website and get these error messages:

```
core.js:5873 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined
    at HeaderComponent_Template (header.component.html:2)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:11930)
    at refreshView (core.js:11777)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:13217)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:11508)
    at refreshView (core.js:11829)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:13217)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:11508)
    at refreshView (core.js:11829)
    at renderComponentOrTemplate (core.js:11903)
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:5873
handleError @ core.js:5926
(anonymous) @ core.js:42696
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:365
run @ zone-evergreen.js:124
runOutsideAngular @ core.js:41093
tick @ core.js:42693
_loadComponent @ core.js:42733
bootstrap @ core.js:42659
(anonymous) @ core.js:42251
_moduleDoBootstrap @ core.js:42247
(anonymous) @ core.js:42202
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:365
onInvoke @ core.js:41257
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:364
run @ zone-evergreen.js:124
(anonymous) @ zone-evergreen.js:851
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:400
onInvokeTask @ core.js:41235
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:399
runTask @ zone-evergreen.js:168
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone-evergreen.js:570
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone-evergreen.js:553
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:389
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:211
scheduleMicroTask @ zone-evergreen.js:231
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone-evergreen.js:841
then @ zone-evergreen.js:967
bootstrapModule @ core.js:42232
./src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:79
0 @ main.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:79
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
core.js:40451 Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
core.js:5873 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined
    at HomeComponent_Template (home.component.html:3)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:11930)
    at refreshView (core.js:11777)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:13217)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:11508)
    at refreshView (core.js:11829)
    at refreshDynamicEmbeddedViews (core.js:13142)
    at refreshView (core.js:11800)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:13217)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:11508)
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:5873
handleError @ core.js:5926
(anonymous) @ core.js:42696
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:365
run @ zone-evergreen.js:124
runOutsideAngular @ core.js:41093
tick @ core.js:42693
(anonymous) @ core.js:42533
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:365
onInvoke @ core.js:41257
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:364
run @ zone-evergreen.js:124
run @ core.js:41032
next @ core.js:42530
schedulerFn @ core.js:36857
__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:183
next @ Subscriber.js:122
_next @ Subscriber.js:72
next @ Subscriber.js:49
next @ Subject.js:39
emit @ core.js:36819
checkStable @ core.js:41171
onHasTask @ core.js:41278
hasTask @ zone-evergreen.js:420
_updateTaskCount @ zone-evergreen.js:441
_updateTaskCount @ zone-evergreen.js:264
runTask @ zone-evergreen.js:185
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone-evergreen.js:570
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone-evergreen.js:553
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:389
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:211
scheduleMicroTask @ zone-evergreen.js:231
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone-evergreen.js:841
then @ zone-evergreen.js:967
bootstrapModule @ core.js:42232
./src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:79
0 @ main.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:79
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
home:1 [Intervention] Slow network is detected. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5636954674692096 for more details. Fallback font will be used while loading: http://localhost:4200/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0
home:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:3443/images/' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
core.js:5873 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined
    at HomeComponent_Template (home.component.html:3)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:11930)
    at refreshView (core.js:11777)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:13217)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:11508)
    at refreshView (core.js:11829)
    at refreshDynamicEmbeddedViews (core.js:13142)
    at refreshView (core.js:11800)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:13217)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:11508)
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:5873
handleError @ core.js:5926
(anonymous) @ core.js:42696
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:365
run @ zone-evergreen.js:124
runOutsideAngular @ core.js:41093
tick @ core.js:42693
(anonymous) @ core.js:42533
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:365
onInvoke @ core.js:41257
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:364
run @ zone-evergreen.js:124
run @ core.js:41032
next @ core.js:42530
schedulerFn @ core.js:36857
__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:183
next @ Subscriber.js:122
_next @ Subscriber.js:72
next @ Subscriber.js:49
next @ Subject.js:39
emit @ core.js:36819
checkStable @ core.js:41171
onLeave @ core.js:41332
onInvokeTask @ core.js:41241
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:399
runTask @ zone-evergreen.js:168
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:481
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:1596
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone-evergreen.js:1622
error (async)
customScheduleGlobal @ zone-evergreen.js:1735
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:386
onScheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:273
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:379
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:211
scheduleEventTask @ zone-evergreen.js:237
(anonymous) @ zone-evergreen.js:1907
(anonymous) @ http.js:2604
_trySubscribe @ Observable.js:42
subscribe @ Observable.js:28
subscribeToResult @ subscribeToResult.js:9
_innerSub @ mergeMap.js:59
_tryNext @ mergeMap.js:53
_next @ mergeMap.js:36
next @ Subscriber.js:49
(anonymous) @ subscribeToArray.js:3
_trySubscribe @ Observable.js:42
subscribe @ Observable.js:28
call @ mergeMap.js:21
subscribe @ Observable.js:23
call @ filter.js:13
subscribe @ Observable.js:23
call @ map.js:16
subscribe @ Observable.js:23
call @ catchError.js:16
subscribe @ Observable.js:23
ngOnInit @ header.component.ts:41
callHook @ core.js:3937
callHooks @ core.js:3901
executeInitAndCheckHooks @ core.js:3842
refreshView @ core.js:11795
refreshComponent @ core.js:13217
refreshChildComponents @ core.js:11508
refreshView @ core.js:11829
renderComponentOrTemplate @ core.js:11903
tickRootContext @ core.js:13379
detectChangesInRootView @ core.js:13413
detectChanges @ core.js:15093
tick @ core.js:42683
_loadComponent @ core.js:42733
bootstrap @ core.js:42659
(anonymous) @ core.js:42251
_moduleDoBootstrap @ core.js:42247
(anonymous) @ core.js:42202
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:365
onInvoke @ core.js:41257
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:364
run @ zone-evergreen.js:124
(anonymous) @ zone-evergreen.js:851
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:400
onInvokeTask @ core.js:41235
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:399
runTask @ zone-evergreen.js:168
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone-evergreen.js:570
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone-evergreen.js:553
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:389
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:211
scheduleMicroTask @ zone-evergreen.js:231
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone-evergreen.js:841
then @ zone-evergreen.js:967
bootstrapModule @ core.js:42232
./src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:79
0 @ main.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:79
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
Show 53 more frames
zone-evergreen.js:2828 GET https://localhost:3443/images/ net::ERR_FAILED
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:2828
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:386
onScheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:273
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:379
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:211
scheduleMacroTask @ zone-evergreen.js:234
scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone @ zone-evergreen.js:1118
(anonymous) @ zone-evergreen.js:2861
proto.<computed> @ zone-evergreen.js:1433
(anonymous) @ http.js:2615
_trySubscribe @ Observable.js:42
subscribe @ Observable.js:28
subscribeToResult @ subscribeToResult.js:9
_innerSub @ mergeMap.js:59
_tryNext @ mergeMap.js:53
_next @ mergeMap.js:36
next @ Subscriber.js:49
(anonymous) @ subscribeToArray.js:3
_trySubscribe @ Observable.js:42
subscribe @ Observable.js:28
call @ mergeMap.js:21
subscribe @ Observable.js:23
call @ filter.js:13
subscribe @ Observable.js:23
call @ map.js:16
subscribe @ Observable.js:23
call @ catchError.js:16
subscribe @ Observable.js:23
ngOnInit @ header.component.ts:41
callHook @ core.js:3937
callHooks @ core.js:3901
executeInitAndCheckHooks @ core.js:3842
refreshView @ core.js:11795
refreshComponent @ core.js:13217
refreshChildComponents @ core.js:11508
refreshView @ core.js:11829
renderComponentOrTemplate @ core.js:11903
tickRootContext @ core.js:13379
detectChangesInRootView @ core.js:13413
detectChanges @ core.js:15093
tick @ core.js:42683
_loadComponent @ core.js:42733
bootstrap @ core.js:42659
(anonymous) @ core.js:42251
_moduleDoBootstrap @ core.js:42247
(anonymous) @ core.js:42202
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:365
onInvoke @ core.js:41257
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:364
run @ zone-evergreen.js:124
(anonymous) @ zone-evergreen.js:851
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:400
onInvokeTask @ core.js:41235
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:399
runTask @ zone-evergreen.js:168
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone-evergreen.js:570
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone-evergreen.js:553
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:389
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:211
scheduleMicroTask @ zone-evergreen.js:231
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone-evergreen.js:841
then @ zone-evergreen.js:967
bootstrapModule @ core.js:42232
./src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:79
0 @ main.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:79
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
Show 26 more frames
home:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:3443/images/' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
core.js:5873 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined
    at HomeComponent_Template (home.component.html:3)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:11930)
    at refreshView (core.js:11777)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:13217)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:11508)
    at refreshView (core.js:11829)
    at refreshDynamicEmbeddedViews (core.js:13142)
    at refreshView (core.js:11800)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:13217)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:11508)
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:5873
handleError @ core.js:5926
(anonymous) @ core.js:42696
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:365
run @ zone-evergreen.js:124
runOutsideAngular @ core.js:41093
tick @ core.js:42693
(anonymous) @ core.js:42533
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:365
onInvoke @ core.js:41257
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:364
run @ zone-evergreen.js:124
run @ core.js:41032
next @ core.js:42530
schedulerFn @ core.js:36857
__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:183
next @ Subscriber.js:122
_next @ Subscriber.js:72
next @ Subscriber.js:49
next @ Subject.js:39
emit @ core.js:36819
checkStable @ core.js:41171
onLeave @ core.js:41332
onInvokeTask @ core.js:41241
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:399
runTask @ zone-evergreen.js:168
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:481
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:1596
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone-evergreen.js:1622
error (async)
customScheduleGlobal @ zone-evergreen.js:1735
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:386
onScheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:273
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:379
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:211
scheduleEventTask @ zone-evergreen.js:237
(anonymous) @ zone-evergreen.js:1907
(anonymous) @ http.js:2604
_trySubscribe @ Observable.js:42
subscribe @ Observable.js:28
subscribeToResult @ subscribeToResult.js:9
_innerSub @ mergeMap.js:59
_tryNext @ mergeMap.js:53
_next @ mergeMap.js:36
next @ Subscriber.js:49
(anonymous) @ subscribeToArray.js:3
_trySubscribe @ Observable.js:42
subscribe @ Observable.js:28
call @ mergeMap.js:21
subscribe @ Observable.js:23
call @ filter.js:13
subscribe @ Observable.js:23
call @ map.js:16
subscribe @ Observable.js:23
call @ catchError.js:16
subscribe @ Observable.js:23
ngOnInit @ home.component.ts:21
callHook @ core.js:3937
callHooks @ core.js:3901
executeInitAndCheckHooks @ core.js:3842
refreshView @ core.js:11795
refreshDynamicEmbeddedViews @ core.js:13142
refreshView @ core.js:11800
refreshComponent @ core.js:13217
refreshChildComponents @ core.js:11508
refreshView @ core.js:11829
renderComponentOrTemplate @ core.js:11903
tickRootContext @ core.js:13379
detectChangesInRootView @ core.js:13413
detectChanges @ core.js:15093
tick @ core.js:42683
(anonymous) @ core.js:42533
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:365
onInvoke @ core.js:41257
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:364
run @ zone-evergreen.js:124
run @ core.js:41032
next @ core.js:42530
schedulerFn @ core.js:36857
__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:183
next @ Subscriber.js:122
_next @ Subscriber.js:72
next @ Subscriber.js:49
next @ Subject.js:39
emit @ core.js:36819
checkStable @ core.js:41171
onHasTask @ core.js:41278
hasTask @ zone-evergreen.js:420
_updateTaskCount @ zone-evergreen.js:441
_updateTaskCount @ zone-evergreen.js:264
runTask @ zone-evergreen.js:185
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone-evergreen.js:570
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone-evergreen.js:553
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:389
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:211
scheduleMicroTask @ zone-evergreen.js:231
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone-evergreen.js:841
then @ zone-evergreen.js:967
bootstrapModule @ core.js:42232
./src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:79
0 @ main.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:79
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
Show 61 more frames
zone-evergreen.js:2828 GET https://localhost:3443/images/ net::ERR_FAILED
```

Comment: could you provide the header component codes?

Comment: @MohammedYousry: I added them in EDIT part.

Comment: Can you share your project in github? You have splitted in two questions and it's hard to follow your code / issue

Comment: @Valijon: OK, I put all the project here: https://github.com/freemind12/test

Comment: @Valijon: Could you find the problem?

Answer (score 1):

it seems you need to use `forkJoin RxJs` operator to combine these two `observables` into one subscription, as long as the observables are not related to each other, and you are interested only in the final results of both of them

check the documentation for more info [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin)

it's something like Promise.all() if you are familiar with promises

so the header component ngOnInit may look something like that

```
ngOnInit() {

  let userObs = this.authService.getUsername(); // the user observable
  let imagesObs = this.imageService.getImages(); // the images observable

  this.subscription = forkJoin([userObs, imagesObs]).subscribe(results => {
    // results[0] is the user
    // results[1] is the images
    this.username = results[0];

    let images = results[1];
    this.logo_image = images.find(image => image.destination == 'logo.png');
  });
}
```

do not forget to import `forkJoin` from `rxjs`

also, make sure that the results are coming back from the server as you needed exactly, maybe there is no images back from the server

Comment: Thank you very much Mohammad, but I have some questions. In the EDIT2 part of my question I added a code I saw in a tutorial and it works fine, but why mine doesn't work and I must modify it like what you said?

Comment: I also want to know, is this way best way for doing such thing or there is better way? What I want to do is storing some default images like logo, header,etc in MongoDB and use them at my website written in Angular.

Comment: Great that it's working now, could you mark this as the answer to your question so anyone need it can find it easily?, regarding the observables, it's like promises, if you're subscribing to two observables, you have to merge them (or nest them, make one subscription inside the other one) if they are related or fork them if they are not related

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work and gives me the same error as before!

Comment: are you sure the images array is returned from the back-end correctly?

Comment: How can I see that?

Comment: In Postman when I send a POST request to "https://localhost:3443/public/images/logo.png" it replies with "Not Found 404" message! But I can see the images in the directory.

Comment: In the `app.js` I specified the imageRouter.js` like this: `app.use('/public/images',imagesRouter);`