# Is it possible to see an image using postman?

Tags: node.js, rest, express, mongoose, http-status-code-404

I have created a Node.JS REST API server, and tried to test it by sending a GET request on `https://localhost:3443/public/images/logo.png` that `logo.png` image exist and I can see it in the directory. But the Postman gives me `Not Found 404` error message.

This is my `imagesRouter.js`:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const Images = require('../models/images');
var authenticate = require('../authenticate');

const imagesRouter = express.Router();
const cors = require('./cors');

imagesRouter.use(bodyParser.json());

imagesRouter.options('*', cors.corsWithOptions, (req, res) => { res.sendStatus(200); } );


imagesRouter.route('/')
//.options(cors.corsWithOptions, (req, res) => { res.sendStatus(200); })
.get(cors.cors, (req,res,next) => {
    Images.find({})
    .then((images) => {
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.json(images);

    }, (err) => next(err))
    .catch((err) => next(err));
})



module.exports = imagesRouter;
```

And this is my `app.js` file:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/usersRouter');
var imagesRouter = require('./routes/imagesRouter');
const uploadRouter = require('./routes/uploadRouter');

const Images = require('./models/images');




//const uploadRouter = require('./routes/uploadRouter');
//const favoriteRouter = require('./routes/favoriteRouter')
var config = require('./config');

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
//mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');

var passport = require('passport');
var authenticate = require('./authenticate');

// Connection URL
const url = config.mongoUrl;
const connect = mongoose.connect(url, {
    //useMongoClient: true,
    /* other options */
     useNewUrlParser: true ,
     useUnifiedTopology: true 
  });

connect.then((db) => {
    console.log("Connected correctly to server");
}, (err) => { console.log(err); });

var app = express();

// Secure traffic only
app.all('*', (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.secure) {
    return next();
  }
  else {
    res.redirect(307, 'https://' + req.hostname + ':' + app.get('secPort') + req.url);
  }
});

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));



app.use(passport.initialize());

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/public/images',imagesRouter);
app.use('/imageUpload',uploadRouter);

//app.use('/imageUpload',uploadRouter);
//app.use('/favorites',favoriteRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

EDIT: This is my app files tree:

[image]

Comment: How does your directory structure look? Is the file located at "public/images/logo.png" relative to the root of the app.js?

Comment: @abondoa: I put my app files tree in the EDIT part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to specify the base of the static router to point to the public folder. You are currently "mounting" the public folder on the root route in the current code. You can change this line

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

To:

`app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

Alternatively, you can call the endpoint from postman (or any other client) as: `https://localhost:3443/images/logo.png`

Comment: Thank you very much abondon, can you help me also in this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61119340/core-js5873-error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-destination-of-undefined/61122394?noredirect=1#comment108137975_61122394